# Angular7 External Jquery Plugin - Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, webpack, tsconfig

I'm having a hard time converting a jquery template to angular7. The original template has its own assets folder that contains several .js files that I need to load in order to get it to work.

When I start the application up with: `ng serve` I get the following error in the **browser**:

> import $ from 'jquery';
>       Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

tsconfig.json

```
 "types": [ "jquery" ],
```

angular.json, under scripts

```
 "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "./src/assets/js/SEVERAL_JS_FILES.js"]
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.19",
"popper.js": "^1.14.4",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
```

},

Could someone help me to understand this better? I was thinking that I might use Babel or a separate package to handle this compilation.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you npm install. That aside, rewrite the legacy stuff in Angular and don't install jQuery. Why start a new Angular project just to violate it with jQuery?

Comment: I know that it is wrong but that's how I got the layout. I was trying to figure it out a way to load the custom jquery plugins so I don't have to rewrite the whole thing and save some time. Thanks for your insight Adrian =)

Comment: Early wins are not worth the long term pain, importing jQuery in the beginning might seem like a way to save time at the start but the pain that will manifest of the life of the project is not worth it.

Comment: It does make sense Adrian. I'll rewrite the plugins or look if they're available for angular. Thanks for helping me out, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution. It's quite simple but as Adrian commented earlier it's not advised. Thus said, I'm going to use Angular Ready plugins but just in case, here's the answer.

1 - Install Jquery.

```
npm install jquery — save
```

2 - Load in your angular.json or angular-cli.json under scripts.

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

3 - Download the Jquery plugin that you want via npm.

4 - Load the Jquery plugin min.js in your angular.json or angular-cli.json

5 - Consume your script in an external js file, not inside your typescript.